# Talend - Count row on tOracleInput

Tags: sum, talend

May I ask how to count the row of `tOracleInput` and place it to the `tOracleOutput`. At the same time, can I add the values of that column `SUM(tOracleOutput.OS_BALANCE)`?

Comment: Depending on your setup you may want to do the couting and the summing already in your input select in `tOracleInput`.

Comment: Yes. If this is applicable. But on my tMap, I will filter the tOracleInput first do the count and sum then, insert it in the tOracleOutput

Answer (score 0):

You could use the tAggregateRow component like this:
[image]

You should leave group by paramaters empty and create an output schema that will hold the sum and count. The row generated will then be fed to tOracleOutput.

Comment: To count the inputrows, either add a FlowMeter or turn on the "monitor this connection" feature for the input. Then use a tFlowCatcher to catch this information.

Comment: Can I connect the tMap to tAggregateRow?. I will be needing to filter the 2 tOracleInput first before counting and summing.

Comment: Sure you can. Also consider using tFilterRow in case you just want to filter the rows before counting and summing.

Comment: I still dont know how to do. I've tried connecting the tAggregate row on the tMap but no Luck. i count from field of tOracleInput where I put expressions to filter but it still don't count.